# Where is the syntax error in this TSQL query?

Tags: t-sql

The following TQL query is generated from a tool I'm using but when it's executed there is a syntax error near 'LIKE'. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Does anybody know what's wrong?

The error from SQL Management Studio is "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'."

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM [HistoryReport] AS t0
WHERE (1 <> 0 AND 


    (CASE WHEN (
                (CASE WHEN (t0.[CategoryValue] IS NULL) 
                    THEN NULL 
                    ELSE LOWER(t0.[CategoryValue]) 
                END) IS NULL
        ) 
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE (
            (CASE WHEN (t0.[CategoryValue] IS NULL) 
                THEN NULL 
                ELSE LOWER(t0.[CategoryValue]) 
            END) LIKE 'U' + '%'     
        )
    END) <> 0)
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I edited the original question and added the error message.

Comment: What tool is this? The generated query seems pretty horrible and unsargable.

Comment: what you are matching ? I mean whats your objective here ?

Comment: OK, that is just too ugly. What logic are you trying to implement, it can likely be done in 2 lines...

Comment: The tool is IQToolkit (IQuerable toolkit). I agree it's rather ugly but I'd like to figure out the cause of the error so I can track down the bug in IQToolkit.

Comment: The problem with these "toolkit wizards" is it makes people think in terms of "how the toolkit works". Anyone who has commented here could give you a fairly simple SQL answer... but you have to tell us what you are doing without using IQToolkit speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things, It seems very strange that you are testing if a value is null, and returning null if it is and the value if it isn't. Then you're checking for nulls again in the branch of code that is only executed if the value is definitely not null. A bit unnecessary and very confusing. In addition, I suspect your comparison with  `NULL` isn't going to work the way you think it is since `NULL <> 0` will evaluate to `NULL` by default.

As an aside: normally, in SQL SERVER, strings are case-insensitive (unless you configure the column or server with a case-sensitive collation which is somewhat uncommon.)

I'm trying hard to figure out what you actually mean, here is a syntactically correct version of what I think you're trying to do:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM [HistoryReport] AS t0
WHERE (1 <> 0 AND LOWER(t0.categoryValue) like 'U' + '%')
```

Basically your query states that if `t0.categoryValue` is `null`, return `null` otherwise convert `t0.categoryvalue` to lowercase and compare, using `like`, to 'U%' and return true if the `LIKE` comparison returns true. The query above accomplishes the same thing.

IF you aren't using a case-sensitive collation, you can remove LOWER() since it only adds cost and prevents any index usage.

Now, in SQL Server's world `NULL` means 'unknown' so asking "Does this unknown value = 0" can only give the answer "I don't know." This confuses a lot of people because they expect "NULL==NULL" which works in some languages, but in SQL Sever you're basically asking "Is this unknown value the same as this other unknown value" and the answer is, again, unknown.

So I guess my only follow-up question, is how to do you want nulls to be treated?

Also, as to your original question, it would appear that expressions like your `LIKE 'U' + '%'` don't like being in the middle of `CASE` statements.

[BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) states the syntax is:

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

and that:

> THEN result_expression Is the expression returned when
>   input_expression equals when_expression evaluates to TRUE, or
>   Boolean_expression evaluates to TRUE. result expression is any valid
>   expression.

And what you have with `LIKE` seems like it should be a valid expression but it appears that `LIKE` is on the fringe of valid operatiors.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I haven't figured out the cause of the error but I think the information you provided likely contains some clues.